Braintree android sdk
Currently i have the php backend server to retrieve the client token, i had already success retrieve the client token, but when i run the app the app keep crashing and i get the error bellow
Error:
2024-04-27 18:38:21.930  8322-8322  AndroidRuntime          com.example.test                     E  FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.example.test, PID: 8322 java.lang.IllegalStateException: LifecycleOwner com.example.test.MainActivity@cd67528 is attempting to register while current state is RESUMED. LifecycleOwners must call register before they are STARTED. at androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultRegistry.register(ActivityResultRegistry.java:121) at com.braintreepayments.api.DropInLifecycleObserver.onCreate(DropInLifecycleObserver.java:30) at androidx.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleObserverAdapter.onStateChanged(DefaultLifecycleObserverAdapter.kt:24) at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry$ObserverWithState.dispatchEvent(LifecycleRegistry.kt:314) at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.addObserver(LifecycleRegistry.kt:192) at com.braintreepayments.api.DropInClient.addObserver(DropInClient.java:187) at com.braintreepayments.api.DropInClient.<init>(DropInClient.java:181) at com.braintreepayments.api.DropInClient.<init>(DropInClient.java:167) at com.braintreepayments.api.DropInClient.<init>(DropInClient.java:94) at com.example.test.MainActivity.setupBraintreeClient(MainActivity.kt:48) at com.example.test.MainActivity.fetchClientToken$lambda$0(MainActivity.kt:37) at com.example.test.MainActivity.$r8$lambda$CPOENU43zYv7y01wcIs8nsVgg9o(Unknown Source:0) at com.example.test.MainActivity$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.onResponse(Unknown Source:4) at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:82) at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:29) at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:102) at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:958) at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:205) at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:294) at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8177) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:552) at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:971) 2024-04-27 18:38:21.994   597-684   ActivityTaskManager     system_server                        W    Force finishing activity com.example.test/.MainActivity 
I had already try a lot of method from GPT still cannot TT
I just want to let my app able to run success. And can let the user to login paypal account.
I am a beginner i really try it for few days alrdy but still cant find solution.
Source code : https://pastebin.com/Mv6TjJ8t

Please do not links to code. You need to paste all relevant code parts as text directly into the question.
